# Jquery validation is working but the ajax is not submitted

Tags: ajax

I'm trying to validate fields inside the form and then fire a function to submit the form using Ajax, the validation is working very well, but the ajax is not working at all

can you please help me figure the solution out

```
$(function() {
            $.validator.addMethod("urlRegex", function(value, element) {
        return this.optional(element) ||regex here .test(value);
    }, "this should be url.");

             $("#songvalid").validate({
      rules:
      {
            song: 
            {
            required: true,
            urlRegex: true
            }
       },

       messages:
       {
            song: 
            {
            urlRegex:"من فضلك أدخل حروف وأرقام فقط"
        }

       },
       submitHandler: function(form){

                $("#error").fadeOut();
                $("#song-btn").html('<img src="btn-ajax-loader.gif" /> &nbsp; انتظر لحظات ...', );


        $.ajax({
            url: 'song_process.php',
            type: this.method,
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function(responsd) {

                if(responsd=="song"){
                        $("#song-btn").html('&nbsp; تم الإرسال');
                    }
                    else{

                        $("#error").fadeIn(1000, function(){                        
                $("#error").html('<div class="alert alert-danger"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span> &nbsp; '+responsd+' !%</div>');
                                    });
                    }
            }
        });

        return false;

       } 
       });  

});
```

Comment: What does th `console` output ?

Comment: What&#39;s not working? Did you check for JavaScript errors in console?

Comment: the ajax part is not working at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer!

I changed this:

```
type: this.method,
data: $(this).serialize(),
```

to this:

```
type: 'POST',
data: $("#formName").serialize(),
```